# how to use Firebase snapshot with rxdart streams

Tags: dart, flutter, reactive-programming, rxdart

I've a class that has all firebase related functions, and another class to manage state (bloc). How to make them work consistently?.

```
class UserFirebase {

Stream<List<User>> fetchUsers() {
  // I want this function to return a Stream<List<User>> where i can 
  //listen to in UserBloc
  return Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
 }
}



class UserBloc {
   UserFirebase _sService;
   Observable<List<User>> get users => _sService.fetchUsers();
}
```

my approach might be not correct but i wanted to describe the problem.

Comment: You can create streams inside UserBloc and once you successfully get data from firebase just call stream.add(data) method and use steambuilder widget to listen to the stream in the UI layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch this tutorial and just replace the source of the data with firebase:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fahC3ky_zW0

It is what I have done an it works for me. The difference with the tutorial is that, I stream a "List" while the stream  "UnmodifiableListView". Before you stream, you have to map your data to a list.
You can then use the bloc everywhere you want.